# C# SharePoint 2013 client object model list item attachment update Error: version conflict

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, list-item, save

my requirement is I need to update the list item values and if list item contains attachments I need to override with the attachments, delete unused attachments from list item.

when I am trying to update list item with attachments, attachments are updating but I am getting

> "version conflict"

error in `clientContext.ExecuteQuery();` statement but properties are not updating, with out attachments list properties are updating but I need to update attachments also.

below is my code, where I am making mistake.

```
  public string updateEventsClient(string eventID, string EventTitle, string EventBody, string location, string EventRecurrenceData, DateTime EventStartDate, DateTime EventEndDate, bool allDayEvent, bool isRecurring, List<string> attachments, string group, string division, string department, string businessUnit, string category)
    {
        string itemId = "";

        try
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://vr-si-web-qa01/sites/ITForms/";
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyCal");

            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            string queryTxt = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">" + eventID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = queryTxt;

            // 1st update
            ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(query);
            clientContext.Load(items);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            ListItem oListItem = items[0];

            clientContext.Load(oList, l => l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
            clientContext.Load(oListItem, i => i.AttachmentFiles);
            clientContext.Load(oListItem, i => i.Id);
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site, s => s.Url);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            var version = oListItem.FieldValues["_UIVersionString"].ToString();
            double result;
            double.TryParse(version, out result);
             result = result + 1;
             var NewVersion = result;

            oListItem["Title"] = EventTitle;
            oListItem["Description"] = EventBody;


            oListItem.Update();

            var site = "http://vr-si-web-qa01";
            var site1 = "http://vr-si-web-qa01/sites/ITForms";
            var listurl = oList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
            var listName = "MyCal";


            if (attachments.Count >= 1)
            {

                Attachment att = null;
                foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                {
                    string filename = "";
                    Uri uri = new Uri(attachment);
                    if (uri.IsFile)
                    {
                        filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
                    }


                    var filebyte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(attachment);

                    UploadDocument(site, site1, oListItem, listName, listurl, filename, eventID, filebyte);

                }

            }

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Success");
            return itemId;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return itemId;
        }

    }


    public void UploadDocument(string siteURL, string siteURL1, ListItem listItem, string documentListName, string documentListURL, string documentName, string itemId, byte[] documentStream)
    {

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL1))
        {

            //Get Document List
            List calendarList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentListName);

            var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
            //Assign to content byte[] i.e. documentStream

            fileCreationInformation.Content = documentStream;
            //Allow owerwrite of document

            fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
            //Upload URL

            fileCreationInformation.Url = siteURL + documentListURL + "/Attachments/" + itemId + "/" + documentName;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = calendarList.RootFolder.Files.Add(
                fileCreationInformation);

            calendarList.Update();

            listItem.Update();


            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by moving  `clientContext.ExecuteQuery();` to above update attachments loop.

```
    oListItem["Title"] = EventTitle;
    oListItem["Description"] = EventBody;

    oListItem.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var site = "http://vr-si-web-qa01";

    ....
```

The problem is in client object model once you update the list item will increase version, the object we have has different version with our ClientContext, so once i update list item with ClientContext, I am creating new ClientContext and updating again.

Finally, First I am updating the list item properties,then once properties is updated I am trying to update with new ClientContext and get list item and update one attachment at a time ( not all attachments at once)  update it. it is working.

If you still got "version conflict" problem try to increase the list item version programmatically it will solve the issue.

```
 var version = oListItem.FieldValues["_UIVersionString"].ToString();
 double result;
 double.TryParse(version, out result);
 result = result + 1;
 var NewVersion = result;
 oListItem["owshiddenversion"] = NewVersion;
```